# How android studio Preview work?

Tags: android, android-studio

Here is my problem:The screenshot of preview in android studio is different from the screenshot of my real phone and emulator.how to solve this problem when set layout?How to judge from preview accurately?

---

[image]

it's preview in android studio

---

[image]

it's app on phone screenshot.

---

The bar at the bottom of preview is in an wrong position I think.It's should be lower than where it now is in.What about your guys situation.

Comment: Match screen size setting in your android studio

Comment: did you set a fixed layout height ?

Comment: match screen size? @Amy

Comment: what do you mean to set a fixed layout height?@shuvro

Comment: screen size of your device and emulator should be same

Comment: something like layout height 300dp ?

Comment: no,I set match parent@shuvro

Comment: It's totally the same..It's weird. @VivekMishra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the same device for preview as is selected for your emulator (e.g. Nexus 5, which I think is the default emulator.)

And be sure not to use hardcoded values for spatial relations. I don't see your xml code, but let's say you some element should be 500dp from the top of the screen - that's not good, because it may work on a device you're currently looking at, but a different screen size will fail surely.